# Three matrices side by side error in LaTeX

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to align three matrices side by side in an equation with LaTex, and I keep getting **many** errors. I'm a beginner to LaTex so please don't send to a similar question because I'm confused about the code and I've only found complex examples.

**What I need to get**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEXQN.jpg

**What I'm getting**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1TPG.jpg

**The code:**

```
\[ A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1      & 0  \\
    0      & \sqrt{2}  \\
    0      & \sqrt{2}  \\
\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}
    1      & 0  & 0 \\
    0      & \sqrt{2}  & \sqrt{2} \\
\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}
    1      & 0  \\
    0      & \sqrt{2}  \\
    0      & \sqrt{2}  \\
\end{bmatrix}

A^{T}A =

\begin{bmatrix}
    1      & 0  \\
    0      & 4  \\
\end{bmatrix}
\]
```

Comment: Try without the empty lines

Comment: Oh it just worked!! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must not be empty lines inside math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[ A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1      & 0  \\
    0      & \sqrt{2}  \\
    0      & \sqrt{2}  \\
\end{bmatrix}
%
\begin{bmatrix}
    1      & 0  & 0 \\
    0      & \sqrt{2}  & \sqrt{2} \\
\end{bmatrix}
%
\begin{bmatrix}
    1      & 0  \\
    0      & \sqrt{2}  \\
    0      & \sqrt{2}  \\
\end{bmatrix}
%
A^{T}A =
%
\begin{bmatrix}
    1      & 0  \\
    0      & 4  \\
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
$ A = 
  \left[ \begin{tabular}{rr}
    1      & 0  \\
    0      & $\sqrt{2}$  \\
    0      & $\sqrt{2}$  \\
\end{tabular}
\right]$
  &
$\left[ \begin{tabular}{rrr}
  1      & 0  & 0 \\
  0      & $\sqrt{2}$  & $\sqrt{2}$ \\
\end{tabular}\right]$
  &
$\left[ \begin{tabular}{rrr}
   1      & 0  \\
   0      & $\sqrt{2}$  \\
   0      & $\sqrt{2}$  \\
\end{tabular} \right]$
&
 $A^{T} A =$
$\left[\begin{tabular}{rr}
  1      & 0  \\
  0      & 4  \\
\end{tabular}
 \right]$
\end{tabular}
 %This is done using a simple tabular environment.
```